# Advanced Custom Field data not showing in Fancybox in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in Wordpress to output an image with a link (also using to add embed code for a custom video player) into posts on an archive page. The output code for the custom field is placed in a div which is hidden and then loads up in fancybox when the .watchsession link is clicked. The problem is, the ACF content doesn't load in the fancybox when called. If I place the code outside of the hidden div it shows. Not sure where I've gone wrong. Code below!

Cheers,

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>    

<a id="fancybox-button" href="#fancybox-content" class="watchsession" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Watch</a>
<div style="display: none;">
   <div id="fancybox-content" style="width:600px; height:400px;overflow: hidden;">
   <img src="<?php the_field('upload_screenshot'); ?>"/>
   </div>
</div>
</article>

<script type="text/javascript">
                    ( function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-button").fancybox({
helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside',
            position : 'top'
        }
    },
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    });
});
    } ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/gy5z9/2/, got any console errors?

Comment: can you confirm if the custom field data is loading successfully because looks like you are trying to load it outside loop and if that is the case then you have to also pass $Post_id to fetch data.

Comment: No console errors. And if I check the HTML when I load the page, Adanced Custom Fields data appears (the image link) in the hidden div, yet doesn't get picked up by the fancybox? The custom field data is within the loop. The script is in the footer. The site is currently in maintenance mode so not publicly available otherwise I could give more of a view of it! There are multiple posts on the archive page, would that affect it in anyway having more than one link to fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to give a unique ID to each post, so changed the href of the opening link to the post id and div id in the fancybox and that fixed it!

Cheers